# Report ProgressChange to UI only sometimes

Tags: c#

Suppose I have some UI, and some Asynchronous Task handler. I can use callback methods/events that link back to the UI and tell it to update its progress display. This is all fine.

But what if I want to change progress on the UI only sometimes? As in, every 10%, I should get a single console output/UI change that would tell me the total/completed, percentage, and the elapsed time. This would require a simple class:

```
class Progress
{
    int completed;
    int total;
    public Progress(int t)
    {
        total =  t;
        completed = 0;
    }

    bool ShouldReportProgress()
    {
        if((int)(total/completed) * 100) % 10 == 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I need help with 2 things: the method "ShouldReportProgress()" is naive and works incorrectly for various reasons (outputs more than once per step, can skip steps entirely), so I'm hoping there's a better way to do that.

I also am assuming that a class like this MUST exist somewhere already. I could write it myself if it doesn't, but it just seems like a logical conclusion of this issue.

Comment: How you suppose x % 10 to be equal 100 ?

Comment: Checkout IProgress<T> documentation.

Comment: FYI, your example class doesn't compile, and has no public members (except the constructor)

Comment: @AndréB That class/interface is perfect if you need to call back to some form on your UI, but it doesn't store the total/completed variables, so they would end up in your processing class. It also has no code for only reporting back intermittently, which is the whole point of what I'm looking for. I might try extending/implementing it though.

Comment: @RufusL I know, it really was just an example. I didn't even copy it from VS, I just wrote it as I was typing up the question.

Comment: @MarkBenovsky Oh, yes that code is totally wrong. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea of how you could create your class. I've added a field that the user can set that specifies the `ReportIncrement`, which is basically stating how often the progress should be reported. There is also an `enum` for `Increment`, which specifies whether or not `ReportIncrement` is a fixed number (i.e. report every 15th completion) or a percentage (i.e. report ever time we complete 10% of the total).

Every time the `Completed` field is changed, a call is made to `ReportProgress`, which then checks to see if progress should actually be reported (and it also takes an argument to force reporting). The checking is done in the `ShouldReport` method, which determines if the current progress is greater than or equal to the last reported progress plus the increment amount:

```
class Progress
{
    public enum Increment
    {
        Percent,
        FixedAmount
    }

    public Increment IncrementType { get; set; }
    public int ReportIncrement { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; }

    private double completed;

    public double Completed
    {
        get { return completed; }
        set
        {
            completed = value;
            ReportProgress();
        }
    }

    public void ReportProgress(bool onlyIfShould = true)
    {
        if (!onlyIfShould || ShouldReport())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"{Completed / Total * 100:0}% complete ({Completed} / {Total})");
            lastReportedAmount = Completed;
        }
    }

    public Progress(int total)
    {
        Total = total;
    }

    private double lastReportedAmount;

    private bool ShouldReport()
    {
        if (Completed >= Total) return true;

        switch (IncrementType)
        {
            case Increment.FixedAmount:
                return lastReportedAmount + ReportIncrement <= Completed;
            case Increment.Percent:
                return lastReportedAmount / Total * 100 + 
                    ReportIncrement <= Completed / Total * 100;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, for example, this class can then be used to report every 10%:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var progress = new Progress(50)
    {
        ReportIncrement = 10,
        IncrementType = Progress.Increment.Percent
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Starting");

    for (int i = 0; i < progress.Total; i++)
    {
        Console.Write('.');
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        progress.Completed++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

[image]

Or every 10th completion:

```
// Same code as above, only this time we specify 'FixedAmount'
var progress = new Progress(50)
{
    ReportIncrement = 10,
    IncrementType = Progress.Increment.FixedAmount
};
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! That bit of code in the ShouldReport() switch statement was exactly what I was trying to figure out. Increment enum is a great idea too.

Is there any easy way to put this class somewhere that it can be accessed publicly, for years to come? I can store it but that's not exactly the idea.

Comment: Glad it helped! You could add it to a dll by creating a new C# class library project.